# How to Pass multiple properties from ajax post call to aspx page webmethod?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am using below code , but I am not getting value of the object  `myObj`. I am not using MVC. I used simple asp.net(C#) here.

- Class file

  ```
  public class MyClass
  {
      public string title { get; set; }
      public string songPath { get; set; }
  }
  ```
- .aspx page

  ```
  [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
  public static string PostData(MyClass myObj)
  {            
      // myObj.title should have value = "song title etc...";            
      // myObj.songPath should have value = "song path edc...";            
      return "done";
  }
  ```
- JS

  ```
  <script type = "text/javascript">
  function PostData() {
      $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "CreateLeave.aspx/PostData",            
          data: { title: "song title etc...", songPath: "song path edc..." },
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          dataType: "json",
          success: OnSuccess,
          failure: function (response) {
              alert("error");
          }
      });
  }
  function OnSuccess(response) {
      alert("success");
  }
  </script>
  ```

Please let me know what I missed here.
Please give me suggestions.
Thanks

Comment: where have you specified that you want to call PostData method?

Comment: @Neel url: "CreateLeave.aspx/PostData", in ajax call

Comment: it is CreateLeave.aspx/GetCurrentTime in your question

Comment: @Neel oh it's mistake in but in my code it's corrected but still not working

Comment: you should return myObj in webmethod

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what if you use multiple parameters in webMethod and then create your object in that method?

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static string PostData(string title, string songPath, //...etc)
{   
    MyClass myObj = new myClass();
    myObj.title = title;           
    myObj.songPath = songPath;
    return "done";
}
```

Comment: but in future I will have 20 to 25 more properties , so is there any other way?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the data property like this in your ajax call

```
data: { "myObj": { title: "song title etc...", songPath: "song path edc..." } }
```